# Docker preserving user generated file while updating the images

Tags: docker

I am new to docker I have containerized my application . When the program runs logs and user images are getting created so when updating the docker with new image these files has to be preserved . What is the correct way of doing

- Can I use host machine file system from docker ?
- Does docker container image get updated on a docker restart (new image is built with same tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can mount the host file system via [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/) into a container. You can also use volumes as a way to preserve data from different container runs.
2. A container is built based upon an image. Only if you build a new container, an updated image *might* be used. Keep in mind that even if an image is updated with the same tag on a remote repository, docker will always reuse the one it already knows locally.

To force a rebuild with an updated image tag, run:

```
 docker build --pull . // will fetch the most current base image and create a new container
```

You can also run:

```
 docker pull {image}:{tag} && docker build .
```

Comment: So if I rebuild the image and restart the container it will use the latest image or the previous image?

Comment: A container will only "use" the image it was built with. This will be referenced from the Dockerfile. Even if you dockerfile based on "latest", it only rebuilds the container with the current image if you run `docker build --pull .`"

Comment: Once a container is created, its state is locked. Think of it as in immutable state. Images are used as a base for containers. Images can be referred in multiple containers, one container will contain of different layered images. A container's image will never change. You have to build a new container.

Comment: Yes, I will read more docs I was in a hurry . Thanks for the help.

Comment: planning to close it :)